# Integration of $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^k}{1-x} dx$

Tags: integration

Solving this using integration by parts and by letting $u = x^k$ and $dv = (1-x)^{-1}$, it follows:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^k}{1-x} dx = -x^{k}\ln(1-x) + k\int_{0}^{1} \ln(1-x)x^{k-1} dx$$
It is known that
$$\ln(1-x) = (1-x) - (1-x)\ln(1-x)$$
But doesn't this make the integration more complicated. Can I obtain a recursive formula for such an integration?

Comment: $$  0 = \ln(1-0) \neq (1-0)-(1-0)\ln(1-0) = 1  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Did you mean $\color{red}\int\ln(1-x)=(1-x)-(1-x)\ln(1-x)+C$?

Comment: Did you intend to restrict $k$ to (positive?) integers?

Comment: Hmm... and then the fact that $\int_0^a \frac{x^k}{1-x} \, dx \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$, for any $a \in (0, 1)$, proves a certain Maclaurin series identity in a restricted range...  (Oh, never mind me.)

Comment: @EricTowers Sorry for not being clear. Yes, you are right as $k$ is a positive integer indeed!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I didn't mention the limits in my description. But yes, you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 2):

Obtain the recursive relationship as follows

$$I_k= \int \frac{x^k}{1-x} dx= \int \frac{x^k-x^{k-1}}{1-x}dx + \int \frac{x^{k-1}}{1-x}dx\\
=-\int x^{k-1} dx + I_{k-1}
=-\frac1k{x^{k}}+ I_{k-1}\\
$$

Comment: That's a very nice and simple way to do it. But assuming $0 \leq x \leq 1$, isn't the sequence obtained is divergent?

Comment: Also, how did you obtain $\int \frac{x^{k} - x^{k-1}}{1-x} dx = \int x^{k-1} dx$ ? Sorry for such a naive question.

Comment: @RestingPlatypus - note $\frac{x^k-x^{k-1}}{1-x}=\frac{(x-1)x^{k-1}}{1-x}=-x^{k-1}$

Comment: @RestingPlatypus - there is singularity at $x=1$, which would cause divergence

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $k$ is an integer, you could write
$$\frac{x^k}{1-x}=\frac{x^k-1+1}{1-x}=\frac 1{1-x}-\frac{x^k-1}{x-1}=\frac 1{1-x}-\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}x^n$$
and integrate termwise.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

That is related to the [Incomplete Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function)

Comment: Looking at the Wikipedia page, the integral turns out to be $B(x; k+1, 0)$, but is this valid? The page says that a Beta function $B(x, y)$ is  defined for complex number inputs x, y such that Re x > 0, Re y > 0.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$ \mathcal{I} = \int_0^1 \frac{x^k}{1-x} \, \mathrm{d}x $$  Now using integration by parts we get
\begin{align*} 
 \mathcal{I}  &= -x^k\, \ln(1-x) \bigg{|}_0^1 + \int_0^1 k \, x^{k-1} \, \ln(1-x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 1 + \int_0^1 k \, x^{k-1} \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty - \frac{x^n}{n} \right) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 1 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{k}{n} \int_0^1 x^{k+n-1} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 1 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{k}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{k+n} \\
&= 1 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{k+n} \right) \hspace{5mm} (1)
\end{align*}

Now remember **Harmonic Series**

(here I am using *i*  and *m* because we have used *n* and *k* in our integral)

$$ \mathrm{H}_m = \sum_{i=1}^{m} \frac{1}{i} $$

We can write $\mathrm{H}_m$ in infinite series representation, see

$$ \mathrm{H}_m = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{i} - \frac{1}{i+m} \right) $$

Using this we can clearly see our (1) is

$$ \boxed{ \mathcal{I} = 1 - \mathrm{H}_k} $$